# JDBC not seeing updated table structure

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, coldfusion

I am using Coldfusion 8 which is connecting to SQL Server 2008, the problem is I have updated a table adding a new column in SSMS, but the JDBC connection is still 'seeing' the table prior to the change. How can I essentially 'refresh' the JDBC connection? Would restarting the cf server work?

Comment: Same questions as on ServerFault:  How are you accessing the table?  SP, inline query, view, etc.?  And are you doing any query caching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you disable "Maintain Connections" on the DSN in the CF Admin you should have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

Restart ColdFusion.

If you add columns to the end of the table, then you won't see this problem. If you add columns or rearrange other columns, then you may need to restart CF to see the change.

Comment: Is there a way to refresh the connection so it 'sees' the updated changes without having to restart? We had a third party company develop our website and they say they've written code that refreshes it every so often, so according to them it's possible, but they're being difficult to reach right now and we need to reflect these updates.